# Neo4j cypher query with variable relationship path length

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm moving my complex user database where users can be on one of many teams, be friends with each other and more to Neo4j. Doing this in a RDBMS was painful and slow, but is simple and blazing with Neo4j. :)

I was hoping there is a way to query for

- a relationship that is 1 hop away and
- another relationship that is 2 hops away

from the same query.

```
START n=node:myIndex(user='345')
MATCH n-[:IS_FRIEND|ON_TEAM*2]-m
RETURN DISTINCT m;
```

The reason is that users that are friends are one edge from each other, but users linked by teams are linked through that team node, so they are two edges away. This query does IS_FRIEND*2 and ON_TEAM*2, which gets teammates (yeah) and friends of friends (boo).

Is there a succinct way in Cypher to get both differing length relations in a single query?

Comment: Joseph, any chance you could do a small example on console.neo4j.org?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote it to return a collection:

```
start person=node(1) 
match person-[:IS_FRIEND]-friend 
with person, collect(distinct friend) as friends 
match person-[:ON_TEAM*2]-teammate 
with person, friends, collect(distinct teammate) as teammates 
return person, friends + filter(dupcheck in teammates: not(dupcheck in friends)) as teammates_and_friends
```

http://console.neo4j.org/r/oo4dvx

thanks for putting together the sample db, Werner.

Comment: That's the ticket. 3ms runtime for me, compared to the other sol'n with the node(*) selector. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have created a small test database at http://console.neo4j.org/?id=sqyz7i

I have also created a query which will work as you described:

```
START n=node(1) 
MATCH n-[:IS_FRIEND]-m 
WITH collect(distinct id(m)) as a, n 
MATCH n-[:ON_TEAM*2]-m 
WITH collect(distinct id(m)) as b, a
START n=node(*) 
WHERE id(n) in a + b
RETURN n
```

Comment: Good call @werner-vesteras!

Comment: @werner-verteras Does the 'node(*)' bound to just the sets a and b? Running a query for the IS_FRIEND part, and for ON_TEAM*2 part separately are consistently 20x faster than the combined query. It seems faster to just run two queries and combine them in Java. Thx.

Comment: @JosephLust I am not sure, but my guess is that `node(*)` means the whole graph.  But this was the best I could do, with a single query.  I am sure this can be done smarter, but cypher is still very new to me.

Comment: Yes, you should try to avoid node(*).

Comment: @WesFreeman Do you know of any approach that would return the result as nodes, without the '*'?  Or is Cypher missing something?  Should we maybe file a feature request?

Comment: @werner-verteras Thx! I'm even newer to Cypher, but learning. I'll ask at the Boston Neo4j meetup next week. As for how the language could function, something like 'n-[:IS_FRIEND|(ON_TEAM*2)]-m' could be used to differentiate the path length selectors.

Comment: I actually have a feature request for an "unwind" function that brings a collection back into single results. Is that what you mean?

Comment: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/30 in case you want to comment or vote on it. :)

Comment: hi @WernerVesterås, can you please comment on my this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947903/search-list-with-mutual-count-2nd-try?noredirect=1#comment26496571_17947903