# Search list with mutual count (2nd try)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I have created fresh dataset to explain my desired result.
and here is the [link](http://console.neo4j.org/r/dxwc8z)

Or you can trigger this command using cypher.

```
create 
(_6  {UserName:"dhansukh", UserProfileID:'1000', EMailID:'f@xyz.com'}),
(_5  {UserName:"dhruv", UserProfileID:'516', EMailID:'e@xyz.com'}),
(_4  {UserName:"dharmistha", UserProfileID:'5262', EMailID:'d@xyz.com'}),
(_3  {UserName:"dinesh", UserProfileID:'995', EMailID:'c@xyz.com'}),
(_2  {UserName:"dharmesh", UserProfileID:'502', EMailID:'b@xyz.com'}),
(_1  {UserName:"manish", UserProfileID:'1', EMailID:'a@xyz.com'}),
_1-[:friends {ApprovalStatus: 1} ]->_2,
_1-[:friends {ApprovalStatus: 1} ]->_3,
_1-[:friends {ApprovalStatus: 2} ]->_5,
_2-[:friends {ApprovalStatus: 1} ]->_3,
_2-[:friends {ApprovalStatus: 1} ]->_5,
_3-[:friends {ApprovalStatus: 1} ]->_4
```

Now I am trying following query, but it is not given me my expected result.

```
START me=node:node_auto_index(UserProfileID = '1'), other=node(*) 
MATCH pMutualFriends=me-[r?:friends]-mf-[r1:friends]-other 
WHERE other.UserName =~ '(?i)dh.*' AND other.UserProfileID <> 1 
RETURN other.UserProfileID, other.UserName, r.ApprovalStatus, COUNT(pMutualFriends) AS mutualCount
```

In the above result set, I have get duplicate records, (due to ApprovalStatus), If I remove ? from relationship, it just shows linked node only, but I want all nodes started with 'dh'. node 6 also missing, don't know why? mutual count also showing wrong in some case. Only that node should be consider in mutual count which is has ApprovalStatus = 1. like login node (eg. node 1) and search nodes both have relationship's property ApprovalStatus = 1.

***EDIT :*** 
My expected result set :

```
UserProfileID  UserName     ApprovalStatus  MutualCount 
-------------  --------     --------------  ----------- 
502            dharmesh     1               2           (node 3 & 5 )
516            dhruv        2               1           (node 2)
5262           dharmistha   null            1           (node 3) 
1000           dhansukh     null            0
```

***EDIT :*** 
I am updating image for clear understanding.

[image]

I am suffering from this issue last 20-25 days, and not getting proper solution, I don't know where is the problem. I have already post this problem many times on stackoverflow.
here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878498/neo4j-search-list-with-mutual-count?noredirect=1#comment26138278_17878498), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917884/join-result-set/17933098?noredirect=1#17933098) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917508/neo4j-invalid-query-error-occured/17924225?noredirect=1#17924225) and many more.

Comment: Please add a table that represents your expected output.

Comment: Yes, an expected outcome table would be appreciated Manish.

Comment: hi @Edward, I have edited my question with expected output.

Comment: hi @peter-neubauer, I have edited my question with expected output.

Comment: @peter-neubauer, Is there any problem with data modelling? or some wrong query executed by me? If not, why I am not getting answer?

Comment: Well, it's still unclear what you want. I made an example at http://console-test.neo4j.org/r/8lloq1 with your initial query. In your desired table, you are expecting a UserProfileID of `5` and `4` which does not exist in your dataset. Node 6 is not linked to anything, but you are mandating at least `(mf)-[:friends]-(other)` which is why it is not in the result set.

Comment: sorry @PeterNeubauer, that i had written by mistak. I have edit that with 516 & 5262, respectively. and node 6 (UserProfileID 1000) is not connected any one. (It is very common thing in social graph, new user who just created account, may have no friends, but it should be also come in search list with mutual count 0). Have I made any mistak?

Comment: @PeterNeubauer, I have updated one image to show you, what I need? thanks

Comment: I think you should index UserName, and start directly with names starting with dh (something like n=node:userindex('UserName:dh*')), it would be much better that loading all nodes, and then restricting to those starting with dh after having traversed all those paths !!!

Comment: @bendaizer, thanks for a good suggestion. but is simple example i have produce here, actual search condition is different. do you checked my query? do you get any idea to solve this? thanks again

Comment: Yes I had a look at it, and I think you shouldn't try to have node 6 at the same time as the others, because it fails to appear when you operate on relationships, as it doesn't have any one ! Instead, you should query for the connected others, and then append to them disconnected nodes

Comment: @bendaizer, I had worked on your suggestion, but till now date I am not getting success. Can you please explain me how do I do? I want all nodes which is not connected with login user or it's friends. in this case mutual contact should be null. I have tried many ways, but all the ways are failed.

Comment: Hi @Manish I'm a bit busy right now, but I'll give it a try later today :)

Comment: Hi @bendaizer, Can you please give some time to me today? I am very much afraid to use neo4j or not. because since 40-45 days I am trying to achieve my goal, but not getting success. Please sir...

Comment: I have been thinking about your problem, and getting all disconnected nodes will hurt neo4j somehow, because it implies that you get through all the nodes and look for all the paths, whereas neo4j was thought and optimized for local queries. Each time you want to find disconnected pieces from a specific node, you will have to go through all the graph, and this won't scale great. I will give you 2 advices here :

Comment: 1/ if you want all connected nodes, you will need to go through a query like this : MATCH n-[*]-connected, which is really really bad for performances if your graph is big and dense.
Instead of connected nodes, you might prefer looking at nodes that are at most 2 hops from your node, ie friends of friends, and treat all the other nodes as "disconnected", and use the following query instead : MATCH n-[*2]-m

Comment: 2/ the logic to find "disconnected" nodes would be outside neo4j. In Java, you might consider using Set objects. You will query once all nodes in a Set, let's call it "all_nodes", and then you will query nodes at depth 1 and 2, let's call "hop_2". Then all you need to do is : all_nodes.removeAll(hop_2), and you'll get all nodes in graph that are not in hop_2.

Comment: Hi @bendaizer, That means it is not possible in a single query using cypher anyhow. right? So, Now question in How facebook is given same functionality using graph database in it's graph search? Is there any way to do with WITH clause? performance is not a issue right now, If it will take 500ms, it is acceptable. thanks

Comment: I'm still not sure it's totally impossible, but I'm sure it's not possible with a short cypher query ! It's far more easier to use the Set approach, you have 2 short cypher queries, and one Java line, and Sets are optimized for this kind of operations ! I've already used this approach for a POC where I had to sort in the middle of a query, and then find an intersection, I split it in 2 and used Sets, and everything went so much smoother :)

Comment: @bendaizer, I am totally new in neo4j. and i am not aware with java too. I am using node.js to build by website. can you please explain in detail with example. I am very thankful to because you are continuously reply me. thanks again.

Comment: I found this library for javascript http://finger-tree.blogspot.fr/2010/09/sets-in-javascript.html
, but if you need more help on this topic, I suggest you open another question as this is a corollary to this one

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, trying to query for connected and disconnected nodes at the same time doesn't seem to be a good idea.

If you want only connected nodes, try the following query :

```
START me=node:node_auto_index(UserName = 'manish') 
MATCH me-[:friends]-mf-[:friends]-other, me-[r?]-other 
WHERE other.UserName! =~ '(?i)dh.*' 
RETURN DISTINCT ID(other), r.ApprovalStatus AS status, count(mf) AS mutual, ID(me) 
ORDER BY mutual DESC , status ASC
```

Please note that I had to add another pattern in the match clause, because your approval status is between (me) and (other), and not between (me) and  (mutual friend), which is what you were doing!

This will return the first 3 lines of your expected answer and ignores dhansukh.

Comment: Thanks @bendaizer. but this query took so much time to fetch result. I had tried what you sugest in your earliar comment above for somthing like n=node:userindex('UserName:dh*')), but it also take a time to execute (about 196057ms), though I have just 26000 users and same relation. why?

Comment: Do you users have a lot of friends (like hundreds for each one of them) ? because if that's the case, the traversal might wander a lot, and it might hurt your query time. If that's not the case, you should check that you have enough RAM.

Comment: Otherwise, you could limit your results to only 1 result to see if that helps, then try 10 etc. If your query returns too many rows, it might take far more time to generate the display

Comment: hi @bendaizer, there is no more relations between my node. approximately it would be average 30 friends for each user ruffly. and total 26000 users stored in database. I have pickup just top 2 records using LIMIT clause. still I am getting result in 250-300 ms average and some times it will take 200000ms. and If I fired same query 2nd time it is giving me result in just 11-12ms. (I think it is fetched from cache) here is my query :

Comment: START me=node:node_auto_index(UserProfileID = '1') MATCH pMutualFriends=me-[r:friends]-mf-[r1:friends]-(other), me-[r2?]-other WHERE other.UserProfileID <> 1 AND other.FirstName =~ '(?i)i.*' AND   r.ApprovalStatus = 1 AND r1.ApprovalStatus = 1 RETURN other.UserProfileID AS UserProfileID, other.UserName AS UserName, other.FirstName + ' ' + other.LastName AS FullName,        other.ImagePath AS ImagePath, other.City AS City, r2.ApprovalStatus AS ApprovalStatus,        COUNT(DISTINCT pMutualFriends) AS TotMutualFriends, 1 AS Sender ORDER BY TotMutualFriends DESC LIMIT 2;

Comment: Is there any problem with my query, or how can i tuneup to increase performance. I want this result in just below 10ms. Is it possible?

Comment: The first time could take time as your caches are cold. The second time takes 11-12 ms as you mentioned so that's pretty good

Comment: thanks for replying @Luanee. but it is not getting result in 11-12ms everytime. most of the time it was taking 150-160ms, sometime it is taking 11-12ms. don't know why? can we increase performance using index? I think this result should be come withing 10ms as per my data. One more thing, I want sender node. see above query where I had write '1 As sender', instead I want to write '(startnode(r) = me) AS sender', but it is throwing error 'Unknown identifier `me`', could you please guide me? thanks

Comment: Hi @bendaizer, As per your answer I have fetch result first 3 lines and ignores dhansukh. Now I want to fetch 'dhansukh' to send 2nd request to neo4j, so can merge both result and finally show to my users. In this query only one record should be fetch (eg. dhansukh) is there any way to do this?

Comment: +1. You can use UNION in 2.0, but in 1.9 you'll need to just make two separate queries.

Answer (score 0):

What about this? http://console-test.neo4j.org/?id=8lloq1

```
START me=node:node_auto_index(UserProfileID = '1'), other=node(*) 
MATCH pMutualFriends=me-[r?:friends]-mf-[r1?:friends]-other 
WHERE other.UserName! =~ '(?i)dh.*' AND other.UserProfileID? <> 1 AND r.ApprovalStatus=1 
RETURN DISTINCT (other.UserProfileID?),ID(other),me.EMailID?, other.EMailID?, other.UserName?, r.ApprovalStatus, COUNT(pMutualFriends) AS mutualCount
```

Comment: thanks @peterneubauer, But result not matched. when I tried to execute your query, It shows me mutual count 1 against node5 (UserProfileID=502) instead of 2. (eg. node 3 & node 5), and ApprovalStatus shows me 1 instead of null against node 3 and 1. I think very small mistake should be there. thanks for reply.

Comment: where is the problem? or it is not possible in neo4j? what do you think @peterneubauer?