# How to get mutual count between not connected nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How to get mutual count between not connected nodes? let me explain first.
Node01 has 3 friends say node2, node3, node4
Node10 has 2 friends (eg. node2, node11)

Node01 and Node10 not connected with any relationship.
still I want to find node2 as mutual.

Is it possible in neo4j using cypher?

for your ready reference I have posted another post [hear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947903/search-list-with-mutual-count-2nd-try?noredirect=1#comment26450479_17947903).

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an example for you based on the neo4j sample data. If you use Neo as the start node, he KNOWS Morpheus and LOVES Trinity. Cypher and Neo share one mutual friend in Morpheus. Trinity is excluded in the WHERE clause because you explicitly don't want to consider any node that has a relationship with the start node Neo.

```
START n=node:node_auto_index(name='Neo') 
MATCH n-[]-(mf)-[]-other 
WHERE NOT n-[]-other 
RETURN n.name, other.name, count(mf)
```

If you want to only consider certain types of relationships, you can replace the `[]` with the explicit relation types `[:FRIEND]`, for example.

You can check out the neo4j console example [here](http://console.neo4j.org/r/ve4akr)

Comment: Thanks @edward, Your example work for me. It is returning those disconnected nodes which has mutual contact between my login user and searched user. but It is still not returning those nodes who is not connected with me and thay have no mutual contacts between login user and search user. As my expected result mutual count should come with null also. thanks

Comment: Did you look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947903/search-list-with-mutual-count-2nd-try?noredirect=1#comment26450479_17947903? here I am explaining what I needed? It is very common in any social network website. my user want to search for some people with its name stared with some words (eg. 'dh'), and I have to show that node which is started from 'dh' with order by mutual count (max first) and AppruvalStatus (show pending first, so user can select/accept him/her first). I think every social networking site doing same thing. So I cann't understand why it is not happening in simple way?