# condition in count function

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Can I put condition in count()? Let me explain.

```
START me=node:node_auto_index(UserProfileID = '1'), other=node(*) 
MATCH pMutualFriends=me-[r?:friends]-mf-[r1:friends]-other 
WHERE other.UserName? =~ '(?i)dh.*' AND other.UserProfileID? <> 1 
RETURN me.EMailID, other.EMailID,other.UserProfileID, other.UserName, r.ApprovalStatus,    COUNT(pMutualFriends) AS mutualCount
```

in above query can I user like this.

```
COUNT(pMutualFriends where r.ApprovalStatus = 1 AND r1.ApprovalStatus =1 )
```

Or may be in other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [`filter` function](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-functions-collection.html#functions-filter) should help you. If you need further assistence, please provide a data sample on http://console.neo4j.org and share it here.

As an example:

```
START me=node:node_auto_index(UserProfileID = '1'), other=node(*) 
MATCH pMutualFriends=me-[r?:friends]-mf-[r1:friends]-other 
WHERE other.UserName? =~ '(?i)dh.*' AND other.UserProfileID? <> 1 
RETURN me.EMailID, other.EMailID,other.UserProfileID, other.UserName, 
  count(filter(x IN r.ApprovalStatus: x=1)), 
  count(filter(x IN r1.ApprovalStatus: x=1))
```

Comment: thanks @stefan-armbruster, Should this work on relationship's property? I have already uploaded sample data here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947903/search-list-with-mutual-count-2nd-try?noredirect=1#comment26542030_17947903

Comment: yes, filter works on relationship properties, see update above.

Comment: Hi @stefan-armbruster, I have check your query. It works fine, but didn't return my expected result. I want node6 also (name:dhansukh) with mutual count 0 or null. please have a look on expected result in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947903/search-list-with-mutual-count-2nd-try?noredirect=1#comment26542030_17947903

Comment: Hello @stefan-armbruster, did you checked my link? any guess?

Comment: I suppose you want to have the number of in- and outgoing friend relationships for a certain user. This looks more like `START me=node:node_auto_index(UserProfileID = '1'), other=node(*) 
MATCH me-[r?:friends]->other<-[r1:friends]-me
WHERE other.UserName? =~ '(?i)dh.*' 
RETURN me.EMailID, other.EMailID,other.UserProfileID?, other.UserName?, 
  count(filter(x IN r.ApprovalStatus: x=1)), 
  count(filter(x IN r1.ApprovalStatus: x=1))`

Comment: @stefan-armbtuster, I want all node starts with 'dh' with it's mutual count with node1. If there is no mutual between search node and node1, in that case it should return null or 0. but record must come started with 'dh'. I think i have explain it very well. but If you do not understand it properly, let me know/

Comment: just a small variation: `START me=node:node_auto_index(UserProfileID = '1'), other=node(*) 
MATCH me-[r?:friends]->other<-[r1?:friends]-me 
WHERE HAS (other.UserName) AND other.UserName? =~ '(?i)dh.*' 
RETURN me.EMailID, other.EMailID?,other.UserProfileID?, other.UserName?, count(filter(x IN r.ApprovalStatus: x=1)), count(filter(x IN r1.ApprovalStatus: x=1))`